# Put a particular image next to a different text for a recycleview using Kotlin

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I want to create a UI where display is kind of linear form with an text beside each image. I have lot of text but few images. So How do I assign a certain image to any random text.

Comment: you sohuld be thankfull to the one who will answer your question coz its more than   a question , its a task/assignment..

Comment: Have you tried using ConstraintLayout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done.

In the `onBindViewHolder` method of the adapter class we can add the following codesnippet.

```
holder?.view?.imageView?.setImageResource(R.drawable.pink)
```

Here pink refers to the name of the image.
I am assuming that we have dropped the images you want to display in the drawable folder.

The above code snippet can be placed in an `if clause` where we are choosing a certain text and the desired view comes.

Comment: Why do you have so many   ?????s? I'm pretty sure at least half of those aren't actually nullable.

Comment: The android-studio automatically shows me that they are nullable and in order to run/build/compile successfully, I had to put the "?" because it wouldn't compile otherwise.